# Exporting lists and saving them as .CSV file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, export

I found this code that has helped me out incredibly with my job. I would like to customize it a little bit more though and for the life of me I can't get it to work. I have no coding knowledge at all so I thought I may be able to get some help from this community.

I would like to include something so that when the files are saved, it's saved in .CSV file format. The code I have is shown below.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
  Dim NumOfColumns As Integer
  Dim RangeToCopy As Range
  Dim RangeOfHeader As Range        'data (range) of header row
  Dim WorkbookCounter As Integer
  Dim RowsInFile                    'how many rows (incl. header) in new files?

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Initialize data
  Set ThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
  WorkbookCounter = 1
  RowsInFile = 101                   'as your example, just 1000 rows per file

  'Copy the data of the first row (header)
  Set RangeOfHeader = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(1, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(1, NumOfColumns))

  For p = 2 To ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step RowsInFile - 1
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

  'Paste the header row in new file
    RangeOfHeader.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

  'Paste the chunk of rows for this file
    Set RangeToCopy = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(p, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(p + RowsInFile - 2, NumOfColumns))
    RangeToCopy.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2")

  'Save the new workbook, and close it
    wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file " & WorkbookCounter
    wb.Close

  'Increment file counter
    WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1
  Next p

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try recording a macro while saving a file as CSV, and then try incorporating that into this code.  If you have problems, post back with the code you tried, and a description of any error(s) you got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juan, If I understand, your only goal is to save as CSV. If that's the case, everyhting you have is correct with the exception of the missing second parameter on the **[SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)** method; which is the [FileFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat).

Ex:

```
Sub SaveAsCSV()

Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "name1", xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering this for me. To clarify, the code that I posted spits out seperate workbooks every 101 rows from the master file but they spit them out in .xlsx and I want them to spit them out in .csv format. Apologies if this is what you gave me, I'm just not not sure where to paste the code in the module...